# Php local server register

Tags: php, sql

I'm making a register/login in php. Right now I'm trying to register via an html formulaire, having fill the input, I'm receiving this in the terminal :

```
[Tue Nov 28 22:57:30 2017] ::1:59017 [200]: /
```

But nothing goes in my database. I'm going crazy, I don't understand what's wrong :

my dbconfig :

```
<?php
$config = [
  "host" => "host",
  "dbname"=>"dbname"
  "user" => "dbuser",
  "password" => "dbpassword",
];

?>
```

my dbconnexion :

```
<?php

require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/../config/dbconfig.php");

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$config["host"].';dbname='.$config["dbname"], $config["user"], $config["password"]);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Erreur !: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
}
```

And finally my index.php :

```
<?php

echo "<h1> BulletProof </h1>";
require './utils/dbconnexion.php';
//session_start();
?>

<form method="POST">
<label>Pseudo: <input type="text" name="nickname_register"/></label><br/>
<label>Mot de passe: <input type="password" name="password_register"/></label><br/>
<input type="submit" value="M'inscrire"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['nickname_register']) && !empty($_POST['nickname_register']) && isset($_POST['password_register']) && !empty($_POST['password_register'])){
    $pseudo_register = htmlspecialchars($_POST['nickname_register']);
    $password_register = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password_register']);
    $password_hash = password_hash($password_register, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $q = $pdo->prepare('INSERT user (nickname, password) VALUES (:nickname, :password');
    $q->bindParam(':nickname', $nickname_register, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindParam(':password', $password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $register = $q->execute();

}


?>
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong ?
I've looked into my syntaxe, my sql request, my info to connect the database, but I don't see anything wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `INSERT` statement syntax which should be `INSERT INTO` :

```
$q = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO user (nickname, password) VALUES (:nickname, :password)');
```

Comment: also `$pseudo_register` != `$nickname_register`

Comment: Thx for your answers, those are stupid mistakes but it's still not register anything in the database, is there something else I am missing ?

Comment: Ok I got the error, it's a missing parenthese, I've been looking at it too much I didn't see those errors, thanks anyway both of you !